# Get all parameters from specific parameter sets

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am having some trouble getting the parameters from a specific parameter set. I have solved it by getting all parameters and using `$parDetails.Name.Contains("FileAttachment")` as an `if` statement.

What I would like instead is to get the parameters from a specific parameter set.

Can someone please help me with this? Below is the code I am currently using.

```
$CommandName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
$ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameter

foreach ($key in $ParameterList.keys) {
    Write-Verbose "Starting loop for $key"
    $parDetails = Get-Variable -Name $key
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Get-Help` to see the parameters? What problem are you solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PSv4+ syntax:

```
# Sample cmdlet and parameter set to inspect.
# To determine all parameter-set names for a given cmdlet, use:
#  (Get-Command $commandName).ParameterSets.Name
$cmd = 'Get-Item'
$paramSet = 'Path'

# Get all parameters associated with the specified parameter set.
$paramsInSet = (Get-Command $cmd).ParameterSets.Where({$_.Name -eq $paramSet}).Parameters

# Output the names of all parameters in the set.
$paramsInSet.Name
```

The above yields:

```
Path
Filter
Include
Exclude
Force
Credential
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
```

Comment: Didn't see parametersets on the command...this is better than what I had.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script which looks for parameters in a specific parameter set (or in all parameter sets).  It should get you what you're looking for.

```
$commandName='Get-ChildItem'
$ParameterSetToMatch='LiteralItems'

$ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $commandName).Parameters.Values

foreach($parameter in $parameterList){
    $parameterSets=$parameter.ParameterSets.Keys
    if($parameterSets -contains '__AllParameterSets'){
        write-host "$($parameter.Name) is in __AllParameterSets"
    } elseif ($parameterSets -contains $parameterSetToMatch ){
        write-host "$($parameter.Name) is in $parameterSetToMatch"
    }
}
```

If you just want the items specifically in the parameterset, here's a shorter version:

```
$commandName='Get-ChildItem'
$ParameterSetToMatch='Items'
$parameterlist |  
    Where-object {$_.ParameterSets.Keys -contains $ParameterSetToMatch} | 
     select-object Name
```